# org.apache.flink.formats.json dependency says Jar not available

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to parse the incoming event using Apache Flink's JsonNodeDeserializerSchema which belongs to package org.apache.flink.formats.json
When I am trying to import the dependency in POM.xml, it says Jar not found but the documentation for the flink says its available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version are you using? This class is only available in master branch (in yet unreleased 1.5 version). If you really want to build against the newest version available, you can use the snapshot repository (with nightly builds):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please let me know whether I can move forward with this unreleased version or not. I am using 1.5 version only but when I am adding dependencies its says JAR not found. I'll try the one you shared. But moving with this unreleased version will be a good option ? in case they change something prior to release, then I'll have to change my code.

Comment: That's true, if sth changes you will have to adjust your code, that is the cost of working against unreleased version. This version is supposed to be released in the begin of april at latest. Nevertheless it is your call to choose the version.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dawid.